# Characters before/after a symbol

Tags: r, string, substring

I have the following string in R: "xxx, yyy. zzz"
I want to get the yyy part only, which are in between "," and "."

I don't want to use regex.

I searched half a day, found many string functions in R but none which deal with "cut before/after a character" function.

Is there such?

Comment: `stringr` is a nice package for such operations. Try `stringr::word(x, 2, sep = ',\\s*|\\.')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be that this suffices:

```
unlist(strsplit("xxx, yyy. zzz","[,.]"))[2] # get yyy with space, or:
gsub(" ","",unlist(strsplit("xxx, yyy. zzz","[,.]")))[2] # remove space
```

Comment: This is what I was looking for! Does "[,.]" considered a character vector? I tried c("," , ".") before but without success.

Comment: The square brackets in this context mean "either-or" or "any character", this is, strsplit separates at a position which is eihter a dot or a comma.(Search for "regular expression square brackets" if still not clear.)

Answer (score 3):

We can use `gsub` to match zero or more characters that are not a `,` (`[^,]*`) from the start (`^`) of the string followed by a `,` followed by zero or more spaces (`\\s*`) or (`!`) a dot (`\\.` - it is a metacharacter meaning any character so it is escaped) followed by other characters (`.*`) until the end of the string (`$`) and replace it with blank (`""`)

```
 gsub("^[^,]*,\\s*|\\..*$", "", str1)
 #[1] "yyy"
```

---

If we don't need `regex` then `strsplit` the string by `,` followed by zero or more spaces or with a `.` and select the second entry after converting the `list` output to `vector` (`[[1]]`)

```
strsplit(str1, ",\\s*|\\.")[[1]][2]
#[1] "yyy"
```

#### data

```
str1 <-  "xxx, yyy. zzz"
```

Comment: @Mark2Bra If you are looking for a non-regex answer, the `[,.]` is also regex

Comment: Are there any regex-free solutions? When typing help for strsplit, in the split section, only regex is being mentioned. . .

Comment: @Mark2Bra If you know the position, then `substr` can be used.  Otherwise, regex is needed here